# How to disable local users on windows 7 using powershell v 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I would like to disable local users on a windows 7 workstation.

In powershell v 5.0 there is a command Disable-LocalUser.

I am looking to do the same in powershell v 2.0

I have tried Disable-LocalUser and it does not work in powershell v 2.0

Disable-LocalUser

I would like the local users disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use WMI.

```
$User = Get-WmiObject 'Win32_UserAccount' -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='Barney.McGraw'"

$User.Disabled = $True

$User.Put()  # Writes changes back through WMI
```

You can also get a result with `[adsi]` but it'll be marginally more work.